# preg match from one keyword to another

Tags: php, preg-match

I use this preg_match to record the information after the word Telephone: and it just records whatever info is on that 1 line, i think once it hits a return carriage to the next line it stops recording. This works great.

```
preg_match('/Telephone: (.*)/', $body, $Telephone);
```

Now i want to do something similar with another keyword but this can span many lines not just 1 line, once the info ends that i need the next line has another keyword that is always the same, its Address.

Here is an example.

Telephone: 090866544
Address: 123 Hello Terrace
Johnstown
Ballamagoo
Spain

Comment:

So i want it to record everything between Address: and Comment: and there is always a colon after each.

This was my futile attempt but i find it hard to grasp preg_match so i am probably doing something silly wrong

```
preg_match('/Address: (.*?)Comment:/', $body, $address);
```

Comment: Did you try the m modifier? preg_match('/Address: (.*?)Comment:/m', $body, $address);

Comment: Tried it, does not work either, in either scenario i just get nothing back at all

Comment: You must add the s modifier.

Comment: Sorry Casimir is correct you need the s modifier not m

Comment: I dunno, bit confused now but '/Active Tables(.*?)Comments/s' does work fine and it doesnt include the Active Tables and Comments in the text which is exactly what i want, i must have had a typo previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the s modifier that allow the dot to match newlines, or you can use this kind of pattern:

```
$string =<<<LOD
Telephone: 090866544
Address: 123 Hello Terrace
Johnstown
Ballamagoo
Spain

Comment:
LOD;

$pattern = '~Address:\s*+\K(?>\S++|\s++(?!\bComment:))+~';
if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $match))
    $result = $match[0];
```

Explanations:

```
Address:\s*+
\K                   # reset all that have been matched before
(?>                  # open an atomic group
   \S++              # all that isn't a white character (space, tab, newline)
  |                  # OR
   \s++(?!\bComment:) # white characters not followed by "Comment:"
)+                   # close the group and repeat one or more times
```

Comment: Thanks, i made an example here, same thing applies but with different keywords, i want to grab everything between Active Tables and Comments: but it doesn't seem to match?

http://www.rubular.com/r/IPkjBMXNwb

Comment: @user1547410: 3 reasons of that: 1) Rubular is not for php but for ruby and doesn't support the `\K`  2) you must not put the delimiters `~` to test a pattern in an online tool. 3) your stop substring is not `Comment:` but `Comments`.... Use http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ as online tool to test your php regex.

Comment: I couldnt get it to work still, but this did work - Active Tables(\w|\W)+Comments:\s but it also includes the Comments text at the end, i want it to include everything before the Comments: but not including it, cant seem to figure out how to do that, i could just strip it out or ignore it but for the sake of learning anyone know?

Comment: '/Active Tables(.*?)Comments/s' also does the same using the tools to test but not sure why that didnt work in my code initially as i did try it